# Select hashes that meet list of requirements

Tags: ruby

I want to select hashes from an array that meet a list of criteria. Since I'm new to Ruby I have no idea what I am doing :) Yes I tried google..

```
@dogs = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "Rover",
    breed: "Siba",
    age: 5
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Barky",
    breed: "Lab",
    age: 12
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Buster",
    breed: "Hound",
    age: 1
  }
]

dogs.select { |dog| dog[:age] > 1 && (dog[:breed] = "Shiba" || dog[:breed] = "Hound") }
```

Comment: So what's the problem/question here? What output are you expecting and what list of requirements do you have? Are you sure you want assignment statements instead of `==` comparisons?

Comment: State the output

Comment: I'm sure you don't want assignments, as `dog[:breed] = "Shiba"` is always logically true. Recall a statement is logically true if it returns anything other than `false` or `nil` (logically false). Writing `=` when you mean [String#==](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-3D-3D) is something everyone does, sometimes even after having coded for many moon.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already noted, `@dogs` and `dogs` are not the same variable and a single equals sign (`=`) is assignment, not equality comparison, which would be two equal signs (`==`).

To explore such code snippets, I heartily recommend [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry), it will immediately flag up little accidents like that:

```
$ pry
[1] pry(main)> @dogs = [
[1] pry(main)*   {  
[1] pry(main)*     id: 0,    
[1] pry(main)*     name: "Rover",    
[1] pry(main)*     breed: "Siba",    
[1] pry(main)*     age: 5    
[1] pry(main)*   },    
[1] pry(main)*   {  
[1] pry(main)*     id: 1,    
[1] pry(main)*     name: "Barky",    
[1] pry(main)*     breed: "Lab",    
[1] pry(main)*     age: 12    
[1] pry(main)*   },    
[1] pry(main)*   {  
[1] pry(main)*     id: 2,    
[1] pry(main)*     name: "Buster",    
[1] pry(main)*     breed: "Hound",    
[1] pry(main)*     age: 1    
[1] pry(main)*   }    
[1] pry(main)* ]  
=> [{:id=>0, :name=>"Rover", :breed=>"Siba", :age=>5},
 {:id=>1, :name=>"Barky", :breed=>"Lab", :age=>12},
 {:id=>2, :name=>"Buster", :breed=>"Hound", :age=>1}]
[2] pry(main)> 
[3] pry(main)> dogs.select { |dog| dog[:age] > 1 && (dog[:breed] = "Shiba" || dog[:breed] = "Hound") }
NameError: undefined local variable or method `dogs' for main:Object
Did you mean?  @dogs
from (pry):21:in `__pry__'
[4] pry(main)> @dogs.select { |dog| dog[:age] > 1 && (dog[:breed] = "Shiba" || dog[:breed] = "Hound") }
=> [{:id=>0, :name=>"Rover", :breed=>"Shiba", :age=>5}, {:id=>1, :name=>"Barky", :breed=>"Shiba", :age=>12}]
[5] pry(main)>
```